# Are generics a form of polymorphism?

Tags: c#

Can we say generics are form of polymorphism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, generics are a form of [parametric polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism#Parametric_polymorphism).